# Is it a normal casual construction using "so that"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> In this example, the tag of the node must be "UL" (unnumbered list) and the link density of the node's content must be greater than seventy, **so that** the node be recognized as a list of references.

Is it correct? What are alternative casual constructions to it?

Comment: "so that the node **is** recognised" - and it's *unordered* list.

Comment: or "... in order for the node to be recognized as..."

Comment: Also, we'd tend to say "the node tag" rather than "the tag of the node".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say:

**The link density of the node's content must be greater than seventy *in order for* the node to be recognized as a list of references.**

or

**The link density of the node's content must be greater than seventy *for* the node to be recognized as a list of references.**

or we can rearrange:

**For the node to be recognized as a list of references, the link density of its content must be greater than seventy.**

"So that" usually refers to an *intention* or *goal*.

**So that they can stay warm this winter, I've bought the children new coats.**

But it is not the goal to determine *that* the node is a list of references. The algorithm's goal is to determine *whether* the node is a list of references. So we would not use "so that" with your sentence.

On the other hand:

**I've intentionally made this node's link density 71, so that it will be recognized as a list of references. The *FindReferenceNodes* algorithm returns 'false' when a node's link density does not exceed 70.**

Comment: Thanks, I prefer your sentence, but could it start with *In order to recognize a node as a list of references...*

Comment: Show me your full sentence, Ahmad. I'd be inclined to begin the sentence with a passive construction  *In order for a node to be recognized as a list of references, ....* rather than your active voice one ("In order to recognize...."), because yours requires that the subject of the main clause be "the algorithm" (i.e. that which recognizes).